# PhpPhantom request returns '405 Not Allowed'. Any way to still scrape the data?

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from site which returns 405 not allowed and also load content using AJAX. Is there a way I can still scrape data using any method?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using following:
$chrome_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36';
    $firefox_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0';
    $ie_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';
    $edge_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063';
    $agents = array($chrome_agent, $firefox_agent, $edge_agent, $ie_agent);
    $user_agent = array_rand(array_flip($agents));

Ref: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/208